# Django prefetch_related's Prefetch, order_by?

Tags: django

I figured the following query:

```
 context['user_artists'] = Artist.objects.filter(users=current_user).all()
```

Coupled with the following usage in templates:

```
{% if user_artists %}
    ...
    {% for artist in user_artists %}
        ....
        <p class="small">last release: {{ artist.release_groups.last.title }}</p>
        <p class="small">date: {{ artist.release_groups.last.release_date }}</p>
```

Was hitting the database 3 times for every artist in the query. I know this can be brought down to 2 by simple saving `.last` in the template, but that still isn't fast enough.

I know I can use `prefetch_related` like so:

```
Artist.objects.filter(users=current_user).prefetch_related(`release_groups`).all()
```

And I also need eliminate he usage of `.last` since it implies another query. I can probably use the template engine's `slice` method to get the last element. But then I have to order the related relationship: meaning, I need `release_group` ordered by its own `release_date` **before** I access them in the template. This must not affect the order of the artist objects.

How can this be done?

Comment: Did you try Prefetch: `Artist.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('release_groups', queryset=ReleaseGroup.objects.order_by('release_date')))`

Comment: This looks like what I need. Tried it  but I'm having trouble assessing the nth element of each artist artist.release_groups|slice:":1" is returning None across the board, and that's before considering I need a specific attribute from that object.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `Prefetch`:

```
Artist.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('release_groups', queryset=ReleaseGroup.objects.order_by('release_date')))
```

To avoid collision with the name, you can set `to_attr` to a different name:

```
Artist.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('release_groups', queryset=ReleaseGroup.objects.order_by('release_date'), to_attr='rgs')).all()
```

You can then access each cached release group in the template like so:

`artist.rgs.0.title`

Comment: How would I then access it in the template?

Comment: @zerohedge `Artist.release_groups.all.0` or `Artist.release_groups.first`

Comment: - that brings back up the number of queries as if prefetch related wasn't used at all.

Comment: That returns: "Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'artist._prefetched_objects_cache.release_groups.0'"

Comment: @zerohedge hm.. are you sure `artist.release_groups.all.0` produced additional queries? It is weird.

Comment: Yes. And I figured out why: name collision. I've suggested an edit to your answer.