# Django Rest How to show all related foreignkey object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have an blog website and my visitors can also comment on my blog posts. Each blog post have multiple comment and I want to show those comment under my each **single blog post**. Assume **Blog1** have 10 comment so all 10 comment will be show under **Blog1**

here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
  comment = models.TextField()
  blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      
      class Meta:
          model = Comment
          fields = '__all__' 


class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        exclude = ("author", "blog_is_published")
        lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'blog_slug'}
        }
```

**views.py:**

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access comments list from blog object using `comment_set` attribute, so add `comment_set` field to your serializer:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    comment_set = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        exclude = ("author", "blog_is_published")
        lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'blog_slug'}
        }
```

Comment: is it possible to apply filter somethings like that `Comment.objects.filter(is_published="approved")` I want to show only approved comment.

Comment: You can use `prefetch_related` to control queryset of related objects. To use it correctly you need to override `get_queryset` method of your view class and use following query there: `Blog.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('comment_set', queryset=Comment.objects.filter(is_published="approved")))`.

Comment: where to import `Prefetch`?

Comment: `from django.db.models import Prefetch` You can find mode details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071822/641249 as well, you may need to use `to_attr` argument to make it work.

Comment: is it also possible to apply pagination for comment in prefetch queryset?

Comment: If you want pagination, I suppose it's better to implement separate endpoint for comments list. Something like `posts/<post_id>/comments`. This way you will be able to add pagination, sorting, filtering, etc.